# Django - how do I update the database with an expression of a field?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

We are using Django for our website, and I want to remove personal information from one of the databases. For example I want to change email addresses to their `id` + `"@example.com"`. I can do it with Python:

```py
for e in UserEmailAddress.objects.all():
    e.email="{}@example.com".format(e.id)
    e.save()
```

But it takes a long time if I have many users. Is there a way to do it with `UserEmailAddress.objects.all().update(...)` with one command that will do the same thing? I tried to use the `F` class but it didn't work, I probably didn't use it correctly.

I also want to filter and exclude by these expressions - for example, query all users except users where their `e.email=="{}@example.com".format(e.id)`. I tried both queries:

```py
from django.db.models import F

el = UserEmailAddress.objects.all().filter(email="{}@example.com".format(F('id')))
print(len(el))

el = UserEmailAddress.objects.all().exclude(email="{}@example.com".format(F('id')))
print(len(el))
```

Both of them return incorrect results (not what I expected).

Comment: That sounds like Concat: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8143362/django-using-an-f-expression-for-a-text-field-in-an-update-call Can you try `UserEmailAddress.objects.all().update(email=Concat('id', Value('@example.com')))` to replace the contents of the email field with `id + '@example.com'` for all user email address objects?

Answer (score 0):

OK, thanks to Nick I found a solution:

```py
from django.db.models import Value
from django.db.models.functions import Concat

UserEmailAddress.objects.all().update(email=Concat('id', Value('@example.com')))

el = UserEmailAddress.objects.all().filter(email=Concat('id', Value('@example.com')))
print(len(el))

el = UserEmailAddress.objects.all().exclude(email=Concat('id', Value('@example.com')))
print(len(el))
```

Reference: [Django: Using an F expression for a text field in an update call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8143362/django-using-an-f-expression-for-a-text-field-in-an-update-call/37097899#37097899)